# FromName recebendo "1" ao enviar o e-mail

Tags: php, phpmailer

Configurei o PHPMailer para enviar formulário de contato e deu tudo certo menos o FromName que chega no e-mail sempre com o numeral 1.

Alguém saberia o que está acontecendo?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Nome:** $nome
                        **E-mail:** $email
                        **Mensagem:** $mensagem
                        **IP:** $ip

";

```
    // Inclui o arquivo class.phpmailer.php localizado na pasta phpmailer
    require 'PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';

    // Inicia a classe PHPMailer
    $mail = new PHPMailer();

    // Define os dados do servidor e tipo de conexão
    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    $mail->IsSMTP(); // Define que a mensagem será SMTP
    $mail->Host = "smtp.meudominio.com.br"; // Endereço do servidor SMTP
    $mail->SMTPAuth = false; // Usa autenticação SMTP? (opcional)

    $mail->Port = 587;


    // Define o remetente
    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    $mail->From = "meuemail@gmail.com"; // Seu e-mail
    $mail->FromName = $remetente; // Seu nome

    // Define os destinatário(s)
    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    $mail->AddAddress('meuemail@gmail.com', 'Contato');


    //$mail->AddCC('ciclano@site.net', 'Ciclano'); // Copia
    //$mail->AddBCC('fulano@dominio.com.br', 'Fulano da Silva');                // Cópia Oculta

    // Define os dados técnicos da Mensagem
    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    $mail->IsHTML(true); // Define que o e-mail será enviado como HTML
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8'; // Charset da mensagem (opcional)

    // Define a mensagem (Texto e Assunto)
    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    $mail->Subject  = "$assunto"; // Assunto da mensagem
    $mail->Body = "$body";


    // Define os anexos (opcional)
    // =-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=-=
    //$mail->AddAttachment("c:/temp/documento.pdf", "novo_nome.pdf");  // Insere um anexo

    // Envia o e-mail
    $enviado = $mail->Send();

    // Limpa os destinatários e os anexos
    $mail->ClearAllRecipients();
    $mail->ClearAttachments();

    // Exibe uma mensagem de resultado
    if ($enviado) {
        echo "<script>alert('Mensagem enviada com sucesso!');</script>";
    } else {
        echo "<script>alert('Erro ao enviar mensagem!');</script>";
        //echo "<b>Informações do erro:</b> <br />" . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }

}
```

?>

Comment: Antes dessa linha: `require 'PHPMailer/class.phpmailer.php';`

Comment: Adicione `print_r($_REQUEST); echo PHP_EOL.'remetente: '.var_dump($remetente); exit;`   
Execute e poste o resultado na própria pergunta.
Isso é apenas para mitigar o que está acontecendo e ajudar a encontrar o problema.

Comment: Tenta fazer assim `$mail->SetFrom('meuemail@gmail.com', $remetente);` e comente o `$mail->From` e `$mail->FromName`

Comment: @DanielOmine, o valor no var_dump apareceu normal.

Comment: ok, tente a sugestão do Augusto

Comment: @Augusto, desse jeito aí deu certo, só precisei mudar a versão do PHPMailer. Muito obrigada!